# Loading a website without opening it in Safari

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2

would like to be able to load a website without loading it in Safari (for server call purposes)

I tried theses two methods but they don t work at all :

```
NSString *connected = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"] encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];
```

and

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

but both these options don t load the website unfortunatley , any reasons ?

Comment: What do you mean "don't load the website?" I don't see any problems when I try to run them. (Other than they block, and so should never be run on the main thread of a non-command-line app).

Comment: both should work. It may well be that google.com checks for the IP header and does not respond when it does not identify a known browser etc. I mean they may prevent google.com from responding to robots. Just guessing of course. In principle both of your attempts should work fine so far. Did you try other web sites?

Comment: You're going to need to provide more info. It works for me too.

Comment: I think he's saying that both those calls don't render the website, they just do a GET. Can you please confirm this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to display the webpage, you should check out the [UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class or [WebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class on OS X.

You may find the following sample code to be useful, [PrintWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PrintWebView/) (OS X), [UICatalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/UICatalog/) (iOS).

If you are trying to download the HTML source of the webpage, then you really don't want to be using  `stringWithContentsOfURL:`. It will block the main thread, for more information see [Synchronous Networking on the Main Thread](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1693/_index.html).